# How to manipulate terminal's history from node js

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, terminal, history

I am building a cli tool in node.js (for mac, bash), which lets you interactively construct a command and run it. for example, you can run "node myTool", and then it asks you some questions and at the end runs a command. The thing is, I want the user to be able to run the final command again by pressing the "up" key. currently, when the user presses "up" he gets: "node myTool", but I want instead to give him the actual command that was running.
I was able to do it in bash, by manipulating the history like this:

```
echo 'final command' >> $HISTFILE &&  history -r $HISTFILE
```

this actually works, and when I press "up" I see "final command", but It doesn't work from node.js by using execSync:

```
execSync(`echo 'final command' >> $HISTFILE &&  history -r $HISTFILE`);
```

It successfully appends "final command" to the history, but for obvious reasons, "history -r" doesn't refresh the terminal.
is there a way to actually refresh the terminal's history for the user to achieve the expected result??

Comment: You're running `history -r` in a subshell, that doesn't modify the user's original shell process.

Comment: In general, there's no direct way to change the state of the calling shell. Programs that need to do this, like `tset`, output the commands that do it, and you're supposed to `eval` it, e.g. `eval "$(tset)"`

Comment: @Barmar so there is no way of changing the calling shell?

Comment: No, sorry. Just like you can't change the calling shell's current directory, or variables in the calling shell.

Comment: @Barmar  if you are sure about it, you can post an answer and I'll marked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `history -r` in a new shell process, not the user's original interactive shell. Each shell process keeps its own history, and reloading the child shell's history has no effect on the parent shell's history.

In general, there's no direct way to modify the state of the parent shell. Programs that are intended to do this work by outputting shell commands. The user makes use of them by getting the output with a command substitution, then using `eval` to execute it (an example of this is `tset`).

So you could change your node.js script to

```
fs.writeFileSync(process.env.HISTFILE, "final command\n", "a");
process.stdout.write(`history -r "$HISTFILE"`);
```

Then you could use it as

```
eval "$(node scriptname.js)"
```

But in this case the script can't do any "normal" output to stdout, since anything it prints will be executed by `eval` rather than displayed on the terminal.